# pymongo insert_one() TypeError when inserting document with embedded documents

Tags: python, json, pymongo, bson

In my script I am trying to insert one document using pymongo from a script. The document also contains an array or embedded documents. When running this code in the Mongo client directly it works. From the script it does not.

I am using MongoDB 4.08 with pymongo 3.8.0 and tried it on both python 2.7.10 and 3.7.3.

Here is the document I would like to insert:

```
{'id': 84646995, 'first': 'AAA', 'last': 'YYY', 'email': 'AAA.YYY@domain.com', 'previous_cars': [{'make': 'BMW', 'model': 'model2'},{'make': 'Mercedes', 'model': 'model1'}]}
```

The purpose of the script is to create test data, one document at a time, and insert it into the collection user afterwards.

```
import pymongo
import random

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client.user # db user with a collection called user

first_names = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
last_names = ["XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ"]
make_list = ["Audi", "BMW", "Mercedes"]
model_list = ["model1", "model2", "model3"]
total = 0

for x in range(10):
    u_id = random.randint(10000000, 99999999)
    first = random.choice(first_names)
    last = random.choice(last_names)
    make1 = random.choice(make_list)
    make2 = random.choice(make_list)
    model1 = random.choice(model_list)
    model2 = random.choice(model_list)

    doc = "{'id': " + str(u_id) + ", 'first': '" + str(first) + "', 'last': '" + str(last) + "', 'email': '" + str(first) + "." + str(last) + "@firma.de', 'previous_cars': [{'make': '" + str(make1) + "', 'model': '" + str(model1) + "'},{'make': '" + str(make2) + "', 'model': '" + str(model2) + "'}]}"

    print(doc)

    db.user.insert_one(doc)
    total += 1

print("Done. Inserted " + str(total) + " documents.")
```

The error I get:

```
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

If I take the output of `print(doc)` and paste it into a python shell (with an open pymongo connection), I get no error. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to insert a string. Change "{..." to {'id'..

Comment: Fantastic, that worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're currently encountering is basically letting you know that you're not passing a dict or any of the supported data structures. - In order for it to work you need to change:

```
doc = "{'id': " + str(u_id) + ", 'first': '" + str(first) + "', 'last': '" + str(last) + "', 'email': '" + str(first) + "." + str(last) + "@firma.de', 'previous_cars': [{'make': '" + str(make1) + "', 'model': '" + str(model1) + "'},{'make': '" + str(make2) + "', 'model': '" + str(model2) + "'}]}"
```

**Into the following:**

```
doc = {'id': str(u_id) ...}
```